# Umbraco Log table is getting filled with At /keepalive/ping.ashx (Referred by: ):

Tags: asp.net, logging, umbraco, ashx, keep-alive

I am getting the following error log entry in every few seconds into one of the website UmbracoLog table...

At /keepalive/ping.ashx (Referred by: ):

Trying to find the solution for the issue for few days without any success.. please see my post in Our Umbraco
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/33930-Error-in-umbracoLog-table-At-keepalivepingashx-%28Referred-by-%29?p=0#comment124646

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using? Also, is this a new install or an existing website that has this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So keepalives are generally used to stop the old CMS backend falling foul of the app pool going to sleep after 20 mins or so.

It sounds like something is happening in your solution that is firing every few seconds which is a bit odd.

If you have nopCommerce installed at all? This post here describes the issue you are having and where to disable the keepalive if you need to.

http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/6895/why-getting-pingashx-on-online-customer-module-.aspx